# How to get rid of the unexpected spaces in H1 block

Tags: html, css, fonts

I try align text in the H1 block with the line above it(techically it is :after pseudo element in H1, whenewer). And I was surprised by strange paddings inside of the blocks.

CSS of the block(computed):

```
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #192A33;
font-family: Lintel-Regular,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga" off, "calt" off;
font-size: 60px;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 72px;
margin-bottom: 32px;
margin-left: 311px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 15px;
position: relative;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

I use normalize.css v3.0.3

Thanks for advises.

[The Problem, marked red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6biw.png)

Comment: Remove `line-height: 72px;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to get rid of that. A glyph is not only the black but also the white around it. This white makes each glyph stand off other glyphs and other lines. This white is carefully chosen by the font designer.

Paddings and margins applied with css are correctly added to this already existing white that makes up the total glyph.

Of course you can counter adjust by choosing a smaller line-height than your font-size and/or negative margins. But that are just hacks (or if ascetically done right you can call it typographical refinement).
It is probably better to just accept the fact that glyphs have white around them.

My point is: your 'strange paddings' or 'problem marked red' is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The section you've marked red is caused by the line-height. The below will reduce the line-height.

```css
h1 { 

box-sizing: border-box;
color: #192A33;
font-family: Lintel-Regular,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga" off, "calt" off;
font-size: 60px;
line-height: 50px;
font-weight: 500;
margin-bottom: 32px;
margin-left: 311px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 15px;
position: relative;
text-transform: uppercase;

}
```

```html
<h1>Test String</h1>
```